How to generate 256 Cryptographic Hash to a field in Azure Data Factory
Can someone let me know how to add a cryptographic hash to a field in Azure Data Factory.
For example, I have an existing table and I would like to add additional column called 'Signature', and I would like to generate a 256 cryptographic hash for the 'Signature' column
I know it's easy to add a column to a table in the copy activity of ADF,see image below, but I don't know how to add a cryptographic hash value to the column

I have tried to modify my query to include a query that will apply the cryptographic hash, but I'm getting a Syntax error: Missing comma between arguments.
The original query is a follows:
@concat('SELECT * FROM ',pipeline().parameters.Domain,'.',pipeline().parameters.TableName)

The new query modifies the above query as follows:
@concat('SELECT *, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(signature AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS Signature FROM ',pipeline().parameters.Domain,'.',pipeline().parameters.TableName)

However, I'm not sure where the missing commas need to be placed.

I think I fixed the query with the following:
@concat('SELECT *, HASHBYTES(SHA2_256, , CAST(signature AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS Signature FROM ',pipeline().parameters.Domain,'.',pipeline().parameters.TableName)

However, when I execute the copy activity I ge the following error:

Details Failure happened on 'Source' side.
'Type=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax
near ','.,Source=Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider,'

I have modified the copy activity as follows, but still getting the same error


have you tried any approach?

Hi @Bhavani, I honestly and truly don't know even where to start. I can easily generate  256 cryptographic hash in python as follows pkeyString = f"SHA2(CONCAT_WS(',',{prKey}),256) as Signature" But haven't a clue in ADF

According to your image, you are using SQL dataset, Once try this query to create new column signature, SELECT *, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST( AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS Signature FROM [schema].[tableName].

Hi @Bhavani, this looks like what I need. If this works I will owe you a beer. Going to check it out now.

Hi @Bhavani, I have updated the question to include your suggestion, however I'm getting the error 'yntax error: Missing comma between arguments'

Hi @Bhavani, I think I had fixed the query, see updated question, however I'm now getting the error Details Failure happened on 'Source' side. 'Type=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near ','.,Source=Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider,'

According to your image, you are using Azure SQL dataset as source in copy activity. Instead of creating Additional column you can use below query to create Signature column as you required:
@concat('SELECT *, HASHBYTES(''SHA2_256'', CAST( content AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS Signature FROM [', pipeline().parameters.schema, '].[', pipeline().parameters.tableName, ']')


It will generate value for signature column at sink as shown below:


I'm almost there. But there is one big problem. In you're example you have generated a signature for the field 'content'. However, you have hardcoded 'content' in your query. Is it possible to generate a signature for all the fields without hardcoding? As you can imagine, hardcoding would be impossible for every field for every table.

Which is probably why I needed to add a new column as I originally mentioned, and somehow add a cryptographic hash to that column.

If you want to get dynamically use data flow instead of using copy activity.

But there is the ability to add dynamci fields - whcih is where I thought you were going? See my update

Hi @Bhavani, thank you very much for your help with this
